# How to remove empty style generated by PostCSS in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, postcss

I am using Vite + PostCSS setup on my svelte, but somehow it generates an empty style. Is there a way to remove it or did I mess up with my setup?

[image: PostCSS with empty style]

`vite.config.js` setup

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
});
```

`svelte.config.js` setup

```js
const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess');

module.exports = {
  preprocess: [
    sveltePreprocess({
      postcss: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

`postcss.config.js` setup (There were tailwindcss and autoprefixer here but removing them doesn't solve the issue)

```js
const config = {
  plugins: [],
};

module.exports = config;
```

`App.svelte` sample

```html
<main>
  <img src="{logo}" alt="Svelte Logo" />
  <h1>Hello Typescript!</h1>
</main>

<script lang="ts">
import logo from './assets/svelte.png';
</script>

<style lang="postcss">
h1 {
  color: green;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Might be an issue with the PostCSS plugin. Try bumping the PostCSS version to the latest version to see if the issue persists. In which case, it might make sense to create an issue on their Github repo.

Comment: I am using updated version and I also tried scaffolding new project with sveltekit only to find out it has the same issue.